# ListView SetWindowTheme issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm now trying to implement a winforms listview control with a style set up by SetWindowTheme() function. Everything works fine, but the default "Explorer" style has vertical lines between columns. How can I remove them?

Comment: This is normal, you can't remove them.  What you *think* might be a ListView in Windows Explorer is not actually a ListView control.  It is a DirectUIHwnd, a completely custom-draw control that Microsoft uses but is not otherwise available to other programs.