# Allow selection in Explorer-style list view to start in the first column

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, listview, windows-7

In Windows 7's Windows Explorer list view ([what allegedly is not list view at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15479540/850848#comment21909836_15479540)) in the Details view, you can start selection marquee in the first (*Name*) column. You just need to start outside the actual name.

[image: Windows 7's Windows Explorer Selection Marquee]

The same is true for default-style list view control in Details view.

But if you set the list view control to the Explorer style (using the [`SetWindowTheme`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-setwindowtheme)), what should mimic the Windows Explorer, this does not work anymore. You can start selection in the second and later columns only.

```cs
SetWindowTheme(listView1.Handle, "explorer", null);
```

Is there any way to make list view mimic the Explorer selection style?

I suppose there's no settings to enable such behavior and this would have to be coded. Like handling the mouse down and triggering selection. But I have no idea how to do that.

Thanks.

Ntb, I'm using C++Builder, but this should be purely Win32 issue. I've tested this with WinForms too (hence the C# sample above).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually there is a way to mimic Explorer selection behavior. It requires a lot of additional declarative work, but it is possible.

You need to get undocumented `IListView` interface via undocumented `LVM_QUERYINTERFACE` message (note that interface declaration and GUIDs are different for Windows Vista and Windows 7+). Details about constants and declarations can be found here:

- [IListView](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/comctl32/controls/listview/interfaces/ilistview/index.htm?tx=25) at Geoff Chappell - Software Analyst or
- [Undocumented List View Features](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35197/Undocumented-List-View-Features) at Code Project.

After acquiring the interface all you need is simply a call to `SetSelectionFlags(1, 1)` method. Voila you are done.

Comment: Thanks! Where did you found the values for `SetSelectionFlags`?

Comment: I've successfully tested this on Windows 7, 8.1 and 10. Does not work on Vista (yes, I've used the Vista-specific GUID/interface); I can retrieve the Vista-specific interface, but the `SetSelectionFlags` does not have any effect. I've experienced no side-effect of sending `LVM_QUERYINTERFACE` message to the list view on Windows XP.

Comment: Good luck with this on future versions of Windows

Comment: @David, of course any undocumented feature can be dropped at any time, but in this particular case it will not break working code. Still ListView is most complicated and puzzled comctrl control, and it seems that MS afraid to touch it when it works (there are bugs that exists for decades now and nobody even tried to fix them), so this solutions will for many years for sure.

Comment: @Martin, I didn't remember exactly how I found it. Probably I was found it on some forum (less likely) or figured it by myself (more likely, because I've spent many days and even weeks experimenting with IListView interface and ListView control in general).

Answer (score 12):

> Is there any way to make list view it mimic the Explorer selection style?

No, `SysListView32` in `explorer` theme does not behave that way. The control used by the modern Explorer is actually `DirectUIHwnd`. And you are not able to use one of them.

The only way to get the behaviour of `DirectUIHwnd` is to code it yourself. I expect that's possible to do but I'd also expect it to be very difficult to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. I was pretty sure I cannot set anything to make it behave like I want. I expect this has to be coded. I just do not know how. Edited the question to make it explicit.

Comment: Well, I answered the original question. Clearly it's possible to make such a control. Explorer is proof of that. Whether it's tractable for you to graft it on to `SysListView32` is a different matter. I'm sceptical.

Comment: Bounty goes to you, as I, unfortunately, did not get any better answer :) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I'd say that part of your problem is that you didn't actually ask for a different answer. I picked out the question that you asked in a quote in my answer. And you asked "is there any way?" That's really a yes/no type of a question. What you want to do, I think, is ask a follow up question that says, "how do I do this?"

Comment: I understand that my original question was not specific enough. But I do not see how to improve it further after my edit. I would have to post the same question again, what does not look like a good idea :)

Comment: My point is that you didn't ask how to it, you asked if it could be done. And so I could answer without actually writing the code to do it. But in any case I think it would be a very big project to extend the list view control that way. I'm not sure you'll ever get comprehensive code from an SO question. You probably need to start coding, and ask specific questions when you hit a problem.